# How can I show an icon instead of text and relocate the menu items in .NET MAUI Shell?

Tags: .net, maui

I am currently trying to implement a application wide menu (the menu should be shown on every page of the application) with two options in it: Help + About in a .NET Maui application. Instead of having a text for the topmost `MenuBarItem`, I want to have an icon to open the menu, similar looking to the dotted icon in Microsoft Teams.

[Dotted Icon Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULACH.png)

In addition to that, the icon should be located on the right side of the window, not on the left side.

I thought the easiest way to do achieve this would be using the `AppShell.xaml` and defining a `MenuBarItem` with some additional `MenuItems`.

```
    <Shell.MenuBarItems>
        <MenuBarItem Text="ExampleMenu">
            <MenuItem Text="Help"/>
            <MenuItem Text="About"/>
        </MenuBarItem>
    </Shell.MenuBarItems>
```

I now have two problems:

- Only the `MenuItem` has a property to bind an image, the `MenuBarItem` does not, is there any way to get an icon instead of a text for the `MenuBarItem`?
- I was not able to relocate the `Shell.MenuBarItems` to the right side of the page, how can I achieve that?

Comment: It's highly recommended to create your own toolbar for this purpose. The toolbar will be included to all pages.

Comment: Are you looking for how to display a menu bar in a .NET MAUI desktop app? You can check this link about [how to create menu bar items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/menu-bar?view=net-maui-7.0#create-menu-bar-items).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of MenuBarItems, I used ToolBarItems to display dotted icon for right side menu. This will display [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PYEl.png)

```
<Shell.ToolbarItems>
<ToolbarItem 
    Text="Home" 
    Order="Secondary" 
    Priority="0"
    Clicked="BtnHomeClicked"/>
<ToolbarItem 
    Text="Settings" 
    Order="Secondary" 
    Priority="1" 
    Clicked="BtnSettingsClicked"/>
<ToolbarItem 
    Text="Exit" 
    Order="Secondary" 
    Priority="2" 
    Clicked="BtnExitClicked"/>
</Shell.ToolbarItems>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.toolbaritem?view=net-maui-7.0